# How do I add a method to a class in a compiled module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

The file `scheduling.py` currently contains nothing. What does it need to contain, so the last statement, `cursor.chronology()`, prints `Hello World`? I do want this method to be available to anything that might be defined by means of `sqlite.connect()`.

```
import sqlite3
import scheduling
db = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.chronology()
```

Answer (score 2):

Both the [`sqlite3.connect()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.connect) and [`sqlite3.onnection.cursor()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.cursor) methods allow you to specify `factory` argument to replace the normal connection or cursor class with your own subclass. You can use these paths to provide your own `cursor.chronology()` method.

So you'd subclass the `sqlite3.Cursor` class to add your custom method:

```
import sqlite3

class ChronologyCursor(sqlite3.Cursor):
    def chronology(self):
        print("Hello World")
        # ...
```

You can then use that class as the `factory` argument to the `cursor()` call:

```
>>> db = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
>>> cursor = db.cursor(factory=ChronologyCursor)
>>> type(cursor)
<class '__main__.ChronologyCursor'>
>>> cursor.chronology()
Hello World
```

You can also use a connection factory (subclassing `sqlite3.connection()`) to always use your cursor class:

```
class ChronologyConnection(sqlite3.Connection):
    def cursor(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if kwargs.get('factory') is None:
            kwargs['factory'] = ChronologyCursor
        return super().cursor(*args, **kwargs)
```

then use `db = sqlite3.connect(':memory:', factory=ChronologyConnection)` to use the new connection class:

```
>>> db = sqlite3.connect(':memory:', factory=ChronologyConnection)
>>> type(db)
<class '__main__.ChronologyConnection'>
>>> cursor = db.cursor()
>>> cursor.chronology()
Hello World
```

I strongly recommend *against* patching the `sqlite3.connect()` function to make the above factory the default, but if you **must** have this be transparent, you can put your own `connect()` function on the `sqlite3` module. The base package is pure Python so you *can* monkey-patch an alternative `connect()` function into it.

So in your `scheduling` module, you'd place the above classes, then use:

```
_sqlite3_connect = sqlite3.connect

def chronology_connect(*args, **kwargs):
    if kwargs.get('factory') is None:
        kwargs['factory'] = ChronologyConnection
    return _sqlite3_connect(*args, **kwargs)

sqlite3.connect = chronology_connect
```

Now importing `scheduling` is enough to make calls to `sqlite3.connect()` use your alternate connection factory:

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> import scheduling
>>> db = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
>>> cursor = db.cursor()
>>> cursor.chronology()
Hello World
>>> type(db)
<class 'scheduling.ChronologyConnection'>
>>> type(cursor)
<class 'scheduling.ChronologyCursor'>
```

The reason you would *not* want to do the above is that it makes `sqlite3.connect()` calls deviate from the norm, act in ways that clash with what the documenation states. That makes your code harder to maintain in the long run. I'd stick with explicit `sqlite3.connect(...., factory=ChronologyConnection)` calls instead.

Comment: Your comments have been helpful. I do want to put my class definitions in chronology.py, because that is part of my actual application, while dummy.py is used to insert test data and debugging code during development.

Whey I put the following:
class ChronologyCursor(sqlite3.Cursor):
 def chronology(self):
  print("Hello World")

in dummy.py, it does exactly what I want. Unfortunately, putting the exact same code in chronology.py yields the error message:

ChronologyCursor is not defined

At least I have it narrowed down to a scope issue. How do I resolve that?

Comment: @vegebond: that's not something I can solve in comments. That'd perhaps be subject of a new question. Make sure to put enough code, as well as the full traceback, into such a question so we can reproduce the issue.